# simple Hammer.js example works on iPhone 6 (iOS 12.4.1) but not on iPhone 7+ (iOS 13.1.2)

Tags: ios, hammer.js

This simple Hammer.js example, which detects swipeleft and swiperight events

https://codepen.io/mindmodel/pen/yLLYGKr

```
    var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

    // listen to events...
    mc.on("swipeleft swiperight", function(ev) {
        myElement.textContent = ev.type +" gesture detected.";
    });
```

works on

iPhone 6 with iOS 12.4.1
Surface Pro 3 with Win10

but does not work on iPhone 7+ with iOS 13.1.2.

On the iPhone 7+, it detects and occasional swipe event, maybe 1/5 or 1/10.  I have not been able to determine any pattern to its success or failure.

On the platforms where it works, it works all the time.

Why isn't it working on iPhone 7+ and is there anything I can do to make it work?

Thanks!

Adam Leffert
https://www.leffert.com

Comment: Interesting to note that zingtouch https://zingchart.github.io/zingtouch/#gestures works perfectly, with no extra effort, on iPhone 6.  On iPhone 7+ I can't get any of the zingtouch demos to respond to tap, swipe, etc.

Comment: So far, AlloyFinger http://alloyteam.github.io/AlloyFinger/ seems to work perfectly on the touch devices I've tested, which are: iPhone 6, iPhone 7+ and Surface Pro 3.

Comment: Given how popular Hammer.js is, I would still like to be able to have the option to use it.